# Determine which thread fires an event

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I am currently working on a c# project which is using the System.Diagnostic.Process method to start up a couple of scripts within a config file.

I have a foreach loop which loops through each script that it needs to start by creating a new thread, setting up the process info and starting the process and redirect the output from that script into the c# program. I am then using the Process.OutputDataReceived event to trigger when the program receives output.

Is there a way in the OutputDataReceived event handler to determine the name of the thread that triggered the event.

The code below creates the threads and starts the thread up.

```
    public void prepareProductStart()
    {
        foreach ( ConfigManagement.ProductSettings product in configManagement.productSettings )
        {
            worker = new Thread(() => startProducts(product.startScript));
            worker.IsBackground = false;
            worker.Name = product.productName;
            worker.Start();
        }
```

When the thread has started it calls this method which will trigger the output event

```
    private void startProducts(string startScript)
    {
        //Thread productThread = new Thread();
        Process startProductProcess = new Process();
        startProductProcess.StartInfo.FileName = startScript;

        startProductProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startProductProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        StringBuilder processOutput = new StringBuilder("");
        startProductProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(startProductProcess_OutputDataReceived);
        startProductProcess.Start();
        startProductProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }
```

The output event looks like below and this event needs to determine the name of the thread so it know what to do with the output.

```
    private void startProductProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Find thread name and perform event based on thread name
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `startProductProcess_OutputDataReceived` will be called from a Thread of the CLR ThreadPool, not yours, so they won't have a "name". However `sender` is the `Process` on which you are doing IO - maybe you could use that to get back to your product name.

Comment: The posted code also runs `startProducts()` on the main thread, typo?

Comment: @Henk Holterman Yep, sorry that was a typo

Comment: Then fix it? Avoids confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since IO callbacks are called on Threads that belong to the CLR ThreadPool and not yours, they don't have a name. So you want to associate your thread name to your process, in fact.

Far from elegant, but well, I guess it works:

Add a `Dictionnary<Process, string> _processTags;` in your class' attributes

Then change `startProducts` to:

```
private void startProducts(string startScript)
{
    //Thread productThread = new Thread();
    Process startProductProcess = new Process();

    // Save tag
    _processTags.Add(startProductProcess, Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

    startProductProcess.StartInfo.FileName = startScript;
    startProductProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startProductProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    StringBuilder processOutput = new StringBuilder("");
    startProductProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(startProductProcess_OutputDataReceived);
    startProductProcess.Start();
    startProductProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
}
```

And `startProductProcess_OutputDataReceived` :

```
private void startProductProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string threadName = _processTags[sender as Process];
    // stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is working, just a side not question, even though it is starting new threads and your answer works great, when I view the threads window in VS2010 it says there aren't any

Comment: Because your thread finish immediately (see your main thread function). They just register IO callbacks, and then they go away.

Comment: Oh I thought the thread would keep running while the System.Diagnostic.Process is running

Comment: +1 for doing it right and not using the thread name as a form of parameter-passing to a completion handler.